# Way to get notified of key:value on expiry

Tags: redis

I have incoming data which i have to aggregate for some time and when the key expires process the data.

I have tried using redis keyspace notifications but it only gives the key.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting an expiry, aggregate the data into a list or set depending on your use case. Put a timestamp in the key itself. For example, if you want to aggregate data for 1 hour, your key can be `mydata:2018-26-06-1300`, `mydata:2018-26-06-1400`, `mydata:2018-26-06-1500` and so on.

Then you simply run a cron job every hour, read all the values from the key, and delete the key when you are done.